# JCrop resizes selection to wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I use [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) and try to set the width and height by a input field.

If I enter 400 pixels in the height field Jcrop resizes the selection area to 279 pixels. I do not unterstand this behavior. It should resize it to the entered 400 pixels..

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oxfep056/6/

HTML:

```
<form>
  X: <input name="x" type="text" readonly /><br />
  Y: <input name="y" type="text" readyonly /><br />
  Width: <input name="w" type="text" onchange="updateSelection(); return false;" /><br />
  Height: <input name="h" type="text" onchange="updateSelection(); return false;" />
</form>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/1300x975/DDD/000.png" />
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('img').Jcrop({
        boxHeight: 800,
        boxWidth: 800,
        setSelect: [163, 122, 1138, 853],
        onChange: addToForm,
        onRelease: addToForm,
        onSelect: addToForm
    },function() {
        jcrop_api = this;
    });
});

function addToForm(Data) {
    var x = Math.floor(Data.x);
    var y = Math.floor(Data.y);
    var w = Math.floor(Data.w);
    var h = Math.floor(Data.h);

    $('form input[name="x"]').val(x);
    $('form input[name="y"]').val(y);
    $('form input[name="w"]').val(w);
    $('form input[name="h"]').val(h);
}

function updateSelection() {
    var x = Math.floor($('form input[name="x"]').val());
    var y = Math.floor($('form input[name="y"]').val());
    var w = Math.floor($('form input[name="w"]').val());
    var h = Math.floor($('form input[name="h"]').val());

    jcrop_api.setSelect([x, y, w, h]);
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle for your problem

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a jCrop user but reading the documentation, I saw that the `setSelect` method expects to receive `[x, y, x2, y2]` instead of `[x, y, w, h]`.

I changed the `updateSelection` method to use the correct calculations.

```
var x2 = w + x;
var y2 = h + y;
```

I also changed the method `Math.floor` to `Math.round`, so the calculations will represent better the real positions set by jCrop.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lfuk1L/

Comment: Oh man, I had read it, but I thought w and h is the same as x2 and y2.. thank you!